# Function Overloading in Python

Tags: object-oriented, python, functional-programming

My book says that function overloading is not possible in python but it asks me questions like:

> WAP to find out the volume of a cube,cuboid and cylinder using function overloading.

Do I have to involve decorators here?

How am I supposed to involve functional overloading in my program?

I saw a similar question where wraps from functools was used but failed to understand it.

If functional overloading is not involved then it is child's play...

P.S-I am in grade 12 and we haven't been taught much about decorators.

Comment: What book are you using? Is it intended to be used with Python? It might just be a bad book.

Comment: You can fake function overloading pretty easily with a **kw argument, though it is not clear that's what is being asked by the book.  True function overloading does not exist in Python.

Comment: My book is a standard book issued by the govt of india(cbse)...and by the way this question is in many of the other indian books...but as shenshin said even i think its been copied from some c++ book as python is just introduced to curriculum... And c++ supports function overloading so the code is easy there.....

Comment: I tried doing this problem with an abstract method....it worked ! That could be an alternative solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're using Python 3.4 or newer, you have access to [`functools.singledispatch`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.singledispatch) (thanks to [PEP 443](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0443/)), which lets you overload functions (preferably unary) much like you would in a language like Java.

If you define your various polyhedra as classes, you can dispatch on their types, like so:

```
import math
from functools import singledispatch


class Cube:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

class Cuboid:
    def __init__(self, x, y, z):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.z = z

class Cylinder:
    def __init__(self, *, r, h):
        self.r = r
        self.h = h

# Mark this function as single-dispatchable.
@singledispatch
def volume(polyhedron):
    pass # Or throw an exception, or something like that.

def _volume_cube(cube):
    return cube.x ** 3

def _volume_cuboid(cuboid):
    return cuboid.x * cuboid.y * cuboid.z

def _volume_cylinder(cylinder):
    return math.pi * (cylinder.r) ** 2 * cylinder.h

# Register handlers for the types for which you can compute volumes.
volume.register(Cube, _volume_cube)
volume.register(Cuboid, _volume_cuboid)
volume.register(Cylinder, _volume_cylinder)
```

Now, you can do this:

```
>>> cube = Cube(4)
>>> volume(cube)
64
>>> cuboid = Cuboid(3, 5, 7)
>>> volume(cuboid)
105
>>> cylinder = Cylinder(r=2, h=4)
>>> volume(cylinder)
50.26548245743669
```

If you're using a version older than 3.4, you don't really have any good options for this sort of transparent single dispatch (though you could always just backport `functools.singledispatch` if you're on an earlier 3.x - it's written in pure Python and I don't think it relies on any new 3.4 features). You could, instead, have a function `volume(cube=None, cuboid=None, cylinder=None)`, or `volume(polyhedron)` and dispatch on `type(polyhedron)` inside the function, or do some magic with `**kwargs`.

All that said, I somehow doubt that your book wants you to use `functools.singledispatch` - I'd hazard a guess that somebody just copied the problems out of a C++ or Java book without really thinking about it.

Answer (score 2):

Python does not support function overloading, however, it does give you the tools to implement it yourself in a fairly straightforward manner.

Using `**kw` in the parameter list will pass all arguments in a dictionary.  In order to simulate function overloading, you test for the existence of parameters yourself and dispatch appropriately:

```
def foo_x_y(x, y):
    print("x is %d y is %d" % (x,y))

def foo_h_l(h, l):
    print("h is %d l is %d" % (h,l))

def foo(**kw):
    if 'x' in kw and 'y' in kw:
        return foo_x_y(kw['x'], kw['y'])
    elif 'h' in kw and 'l' in kw:
        return foo_h_l(kw['h'], kw['l'])

    raise TypeError("foo() takes exactly 2 argument (%d given)" % len(kw))


>> foo(x=1, y=2)
x is 1 y is 2
>> foo(h=2, l=1)
h is 2 l is 1
>> foo(z=1)
File "foo.py", line 18, in <module>
   foo(z=1)
File "foo.py", line 13, in foo
   raise TypeError("foo() takes exactly 2 argument (%d given)" % len(kw))
TypeError: foo() takes exactly 2 argument (1 given)
```

This takes more legwork, but is more flexible than overloading.  It makes it easier to "overload" in ways that involve a single core implementation, for example:

```
def arc_length(**kw):
    if 'diameter' not in kw:
        raise TypeError

    if 'radians' not in kw or 'degrees' not in kw:
        raise TypeError

    if 'radians' in kw and 'degrees' in kw:
        raise TypeError

    diameter = kw['diameter']

    if degrees in kw:
        radians = degrees_to_radians(kw['degrees'])
    else:
        radians = kw['radians'] 

    # calculate arc length using radians and diameter

 arc_length(diameter=10, degrees=30)
 arc_length(diameter=10, radians=1.2)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's possible the book is using incorrect wording and is actually asking you to use OO inheritance.

```
class Shape(object):
    def volume():
        raise NotImplementedError()

class Cube(Shape):
    def __init__(self, side_length):
        self.side = side_length
    def volume():
        return self.side * self.side * self.side

class Cylinder(Shape):
    def volume():
        ...
```